Cannot type login in teams login page, when on another page it is working, python with selenium automation tests
I am writing automation test suite in Python with Selenium, using PageFactory Library. I have spent 5 hours for finding the solution, but still got nothing. I want to login on Microsoft Teams page, but I still get an error "login_input_locator - locator: (css selector, input[type=email]): ElementNotFoundException". I don't know why this element is not found, because when I look for it in dev tools, it is found, the only 1 match. I tried to type some text on saucedemo page to check if sending keys is working or not, and it is. Is there a problem with specific Microsoft Teams page?
Here is my code:
loginTest.py
from pages.loginPage import LoginPage
import pytest
import time


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("init_driver")
class TestLogin():
    def test_login(self):

        login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)
        self.driver.get("https://www.microsoft.com/pl-pl/microsoft-teams/log-in")
        login_page.click_start_working_button_locator()
        login_page.type_login_to_login_input_locator("exampleLogin")
        time.sleep(10)
        assert 1
'''
        login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)
        self.driver.get("https://www.saucedemo.com/v1/")
        login_page.type_login_to_login_input_locator("exampleLogin")
        time.sleep(10)
        assert 1
'''

loginPage.py
from seleniumpagefactory.Pagefactory import PageFactory


class LoginPage(PageFactory):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__()
        self.driver = driver

    locators = {
        'start_working_button_locator': ('css', "a[data-bi-cn=getstarted]"),
        'login_input_locator': ('css', "input[type=email]"),
        #'login_input_locator': ('css', "input[data-test=username]"),
    }

    def click_start_working_button_locator(self):
        self.start_working_button_locator.click()

    def type_login_to_login_input_locator(self, login: str):
        self.login_input_locator.send_keys(login)

When I uncomment codeblock with saucedemo, and last locator in locators object, everything is fine, so sending keys is working, but on Microsoft Teams page it is not :/
Please help me if you are able to, any hint will be valuable
